# Java GC runs cause increase of mem usage on OS

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, garbage-collection

The last days I have seen some behaviour which crashes some assumption of me. Maybe someone can give me an explanation of the following

**The facts**

- We are running Java Applications in Docker Containers in K8s in GCP
- Our base image is `openjdk:8u171-jre-slim-stretch`
- We engaged the flags `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` => so resource limits should be obtained from the container and not from the hosts => IMO that works
- We engaged `XX:MaxRAMFraction=2` so we get about the half of the containers memory limit for the heap => IMO that works
- There is **no** `-Xmx` setting for the JVM
- The only way to influence the JVMs memory is via Kubernetes resource limits => which is exactly what we want

**The thing I do not get**

When GC kicks in (Scavenge or G1) there is an increase in `container memory usage`, but not in the `jvm memory usage`. Why does the GC consume memory from the container? OK, it copies stuff eg from `old gen` to `young gen` so I understand that for a short time more memory is used. But I have expected that this would be taken from the JVM process and not from some kernel process.

Answer (score 0):

While setting memory and CPU limits in one of our K8s cluster running Java pods, we faced some issue where the pod memory usage was shown as a lot higher in Prometheus (and even some pods crashed due to probe errors).

While further analyzing, we figured out that the GC was working hard to free up the memory as the limits were too small compared to the object creation; causing the CPU cycles to be spend on GC; rather than on actual work. We avoided that by increasing the pod memory limit.

So maybe you can increase the maximum memory limits provided to pods and see if this goes away. I am not exactly sure whether this will help you, but thought of sharing in case it might.